# Strange javascript behaviour - error unless 'classes' are defined in correct order

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, easeljs

I have a very strange problem with javascript and easel js.

I am using the easel.js library and am already fairly far into the construction of a project using it.

I am attempting to have a 'class' (I know they aren't technically classes in javascript but I will use this terminology for lack of a better word) inherit the Shape class from easel js, and then have another class inherit that. So it would be something like this:

easeljs.Shape --> MenuButton --> BuildingButton

The code I am using looks like this:

```
BuildingButton.prototype = Object.create(MenuButton.prototype);
BuildingButton.prototype.constructor = BuildingButton;

function BuildingButton(){
    MenuButton.call(this);
}

MenuButton.prototype = Object.create(createjs.Shape.prototype);
MenuButton.prototype.constructor = MenuButton;

function MenuButton(){
    createjs.Shape.call(this);
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error with this code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
easeljs-0.7.1.combined.js:8439
```

(line 8439 is pointing to the initialize() function in the Shape() constructor).

now here's the strange thing. If I change the order of the definitions so that the sub class is defined second and not first, it works fine!

```
MenuButton.prototype = Object.create(createjs.Shape.prototype);
MenuButton.prototype.constructor = MenuButton;

function MenuButton(){
    createjs.Shape.call(this);
}

BuildingButton.prototype = Object.create(MenuButton.prototype);
BuildingButton.prototype.constructor = BuildingButton;

function BuildingButton(){
    MenuButton.call(this);
}
```

This is very confusing as I can't seem to figure out why on earth this is happening. I could just make sure I define them in the correct order and leave it be, but I have all my 'classes' in different source files which are then strung together by grunt, which does so alphabetically.
Also, I feel like I may have a big gap in my knowledge of javascript (or maybe easel.js I'm not sure what exactly is causing this behaviour).

Thanks in advance for your help and I hope the question makes sense!

Comment: It is best to split up your project into separate files and used AMD loading e.g. require.js to manage loading dependencies in the proper order. For a few classes it might be easy to do it by hand but this will become much harder as your project grows in size.

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot. I didn't realize that a tool like this existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> MenuButton.prototype = Object.create(createjs.Shape.prototype);
> …
> BuildingButton.prototype = Object.create(MenuButton.prototype);
> ```

These two statements have a clear dependency and need to be executed in the correct order (for the function declarations the order is irrelevant if placed in the same scope/file, but if in different files they need to be loaded in the correct order obviously).

> I have all my 'classes' in different source files which are then strung together by grunt, which does so alphabetically

That's not a good idea. You should use some build tool/script that allows the declaration of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Read this to clear things out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

In first example you try to inherit from nothing, since `MenuButton.prototype` is not yet defined. To make it work just add `MenuButton.prototype = new createjs.Shape.prototype`(instead of `Object.create()` wich shouldn't be used anymore) to instantiate it first before you can you use it. Your first code is like you are willing to eat a banana before having one.

Comment: Actally, `Menubutton.prototype` *is* defined, but is an object that does not inherit from `Shape.prototype`.

Comment: Ahh I see. So am I right in thinking that when the building button prototype is defined, it is being set to the same as the prototype for the menu button, which at the time had not been set to be equal to the prototype of Shape. What is the benefit of using new createjs.Shape.prototype?

Comment: ```create()``` is a method of ```Object``` constructor. Using ```create()``` or ```new``` does the same but now it's recomended to use ```new``` instead of ```create()``` because it's faster.

Comment: Should use ```create()``` as callback for older browsers that don't support ```new```.